# In the burndown chart, how is 'todo' calculated

Tags: rally

I am trying to pull out burndown information, using the Rally Lookback API.
Unfortuntately, I am not able to get the same numbers, as the burndown chart in the Rally userinterface.

SO, I have gone through all the tasks in my iteration, and checked the revision information, and written down what the todo was, at the end of the day.

This number is the same as the lookback API is giving me, but is 40 hour LESS than what I can see in my burndown chart in Rally.

So, how does Rally actually come up with this number, in the ui?

You can see in the image, that on the 27th, there is 130 hours todo.
But manually going through ToDo at the end of the 27th, I get a total of 90 hours ToDo.
I have added tasks to the iteration later than this date, but I assume they will not appear here (een if they do, the number does not match).

[image: Burndown chart in Rally]

And the data from Lookback + manually taken from Rally UI.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be a project-scoping issue.  The LBAPI doesn't do any scoping for you automatically.  Try turning off "scoping down" in the UI and see if the numbers match.

Comment: No change :(, but there's also no sub projects on this project.

Comment: Are the other date values correct?  I don't suppose anyone changed the workspace timezone around the 27th?  That can cause irregularities.  Although that's typically either a doubling of the values or a missing value.

Comment: Another possible way for this to happen is if work was moved to another project after the 27th.  Could that be the case?

Comment: I've more and more convinced that something strange has happened, in this sprint, that causes my results to be weird.

Answer (score 1):

The screenshot you posted looks like the chart on the new iteration status page. That burndown uses a different data endpoint than the Lookback API. Try adding the Release & Iteration Burndown app (in the app catalog) to a dashboard. This chart uses the Lookback API as its data source, so it should match your calculation. You can set the scoping to Iteration in the settings panel.